# Allow access to stand-alone php file Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, ajax

I am developing a wordpress theme and I want to use `jQuery.load()` to load data from a PHP file in my theme directory called `process.php` to a div in a wordpress page template.

I haven't had any issues with `load()` in the past but Wordpress is preventing me from loading the data or even accessing the process.php file in the browser.

When I navigate to the full path of the file (eg: http://[site]/[theme]/functions/process.php) I get the following error in Chrome

> Internal Server Error.
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator, **@gmial.com and inform them
>   of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that
>   may have caused the error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.`

I've read similar questions but they involve modifying the `.htaccess` file. Does anyone know how to do this from a theme perspective ie: using `$wp_rewrite`.

### EDIT

> Linux Server error log states

```
    [Mon Mar 12 14:00:52 2012] [error] [client 121.98.81.237] SoftException in Application.cpp:245: File "/var/www/vhosts/****.co.nz/httpdocs/npr/wp-content/themes/_s_2/functions/process.php" is writeable by group [Mon Mar 12 14:00:52 2012] [error] [client 121.98.81.237] Premature end of script headers: process.php
```

and this is process.php

```
<?php 
echo "hello from php";
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the questions in here: [tag:ajax]. Read about localize script and `admin-ajax.php`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might find [this](http://byronyasgur.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/frontend-forward-facing-ajax-in-wordpress/) informative, not sure if it will cover what you need but it explains a lot about front end Ajax for WordPress which is not exactly intuitive and it might help you out. In particular you probably need to understand how admin-ajax.php works.